# Linear Transformations between solutions to different hyperboloids

Tags: diophantine-equations, linear-transformations

Is there a way to develop a linear transformation which will always send solutions of one hyperboloid to another?  (for example the hyperboloids:

$$a^2+b^2-c^2=4$$ and $$d^2+e^2-f^2=9$$

)I know that given a solution to one of them (say $(a,b,c)=(2,1,1)$ we can find another through applying a linear transformation used to develop the [Tree of primitive Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples).  However, I'm wondering if there is a way to transform a solution of one hyperboloid to another.  Of course, given a linear transformation building the tree mentioned above, we can apply the inverse, send a fundamental solution of the first hyperboloid to the second and then re-apply the transformation.  However, I think this will only work for one specific solution and not arbitrary ones.